# Get the stop_name with -3 minute of the server time

Tags: mysql

I have the following `behaviour` table as below and I want to get the `stop_name` where the `created_at` is -3 minutes of the server time. How can I get it?

I appreciate any help

**mysql table:**

```
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS behaviour(
          behaviour_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
               stop_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
               stop_distance INT(11) NOT NULL, 
               speed INT(11) NOT NULL,
               direction VARCHAR(30), route INT(11),
               created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I  tried this but I am getting nothing as result:

```
SELECT stop_name FROM `behaviour` WHERE created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found it out I had to change the `<` to `>`

```
SELECT stop_name  FROM behaviour WHERE created_at > (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)
```